# Accumulation of electrons and positrons

Tags: experimental-physics, charge, antimatter

Is it practically possible to accumulate electrons and positrons in a region of space? If yes, is it easy or are there some daunting challenges behind it?

Comment: It’s possible. But they should be separated only by ‘fields’. This can include electric fields. Because even if the positron comes into contact with any mass particle it will annhilate.

Comment: I understand its theoretically possible. But has anyone succeeding in accumulating positrons and electrons separately in laboratory?

Comment: look up for the artificial production part in the positron article of Wikipedia